# How can I stream from computer through Command line?

Tags: streaming

I have several computers at home with webcams attached, and would like to stream from any one of them to my work computer. Is there a way to do this in real time? I can already take pics and record video through command line. Is there a way to stream as well?

Answer (score 2):

This is the command line to stream from my computer:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :inputlave=alsa://hw:0,0 :live-caching=300 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}"
```

I then set up port forwarding on my network to the particular computer I wanted

Then went into vlc on my work computer and opened up to my computers ip address.

as per: 
http://xmodulo.com/2013/09/live-stream-video-webcam-linux.html